# how to make a uitableviewcell unselectable

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am putting together a search string based off 4 tableviewcells, each cell opens a subview and loads a bunch of data the user selects to set the cell of the previous view.

There is an order in which these cells needs to be set so that each preceding list of data in the subview is related to the data set in the parent view.

i.e. in the first cell you select a type of car, in the next cell you look at the models related to the type of car chosen.

That aside The basis of my question is how do I make a cell unselectable until the previous cell/s have been set.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//...
if (indexPath.section == 0) 
    {

if (indexPath.row == 0) // <<--- what could I put in here.... 
        {
//...
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Disallow the cell to track any interaction:

```
[cell setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

or allow interaction, hiding the selection colour, and when clicked, do nothing.

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

- (void) tableViewDidSelectRow.... {
    if(indexPath.row == indexOfCellWithNoUserInteraction) {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the color of the cell until its possible to edit it?

Comment: its all good.. I figured it out.. What I meant was is there a way to say have a cell light gray until it meets a condition then have it change to white so that the user knows they can now select this cell.. but have figured it out.. so all good now :P

Comment: use the second option if you have buttons inside your cell that you want to be selectable (you don't want the whole cell to be selectable - just some button(s) inside it).

Answer (score 7):

Use [`tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942). Return nil for the rows you don't want selected.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift Syntax**

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
```

Comment: That doesn't make it un-selectable; just UIKit will render no highlight when tapped. `didSelectRow...` will still be called.